# Scrolling Header

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to change the style of my header, but this if condition doesn't work and log only (false) in my console and do not change anything, so i was wondering if there is a problem in my syntax or my logic.
note there no error in my console.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var header = $(".hotel-header");
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 200) {
    header.addClass("hotel-header-scroll");
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    header.removeClass("hotel-header-scroll");
    console.log("false");
  }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are running this method when the document is ready , there is an error beacuse when page loads the header scroll is less than 200 therefore else condition run. I have changed `$(document).ready(function()` to `$(window).scroll(function()` this function is called when user scrolls the page. Then the method is called it will check the scroll and return the true or false based upon your condition.Below is working example

```js
$(window).scroll(function() {
  var header = $(".hotel-header");
  var scroll = $(window).scrollTop();
  if (scroll >= 200) {
    header.addClass("hotel-header-scroll");
    console.log("true");
  } else {
    header.removeClass("hotel-header-scroll");
    console.log("false");
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="hotel-header"></div>
<br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br><br>
<h1>hi</h1>
```

Added the `<br>` for some content to scroll.